# Foreach-Object with HashTables?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to check wheter some network drives are mapped via logon script. If they're not mapped, the script should be able to map them but My Foreach-Object in the code below doesn't work. why? Can't I use it on hashtables?

```
$Hash = @{
    "h:" = "\\server\share";
    "i:" = "\\server\share";
    "j:" = "\\server\share";
    "k:" = "\\server\share";
    "p:" = "\\server\share";
    "z:" = "\\server\share";
    }
        $Hash | ForEach-Object
        {
            If (!(Test-Path $_.Name))
            {
                $map = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
                $map.MapNetworkDrive($_.Name, $_.Value, $true)
                Write-Host "Mapped That Stuff"
            }
            else
            {Write-Host ($Hash.Name) + ($Hash.Value)}
        }
```

How do I have to use `foreach` in this situation? Or is there a better way to solve this issue instead of a hashtable or a foreach loop?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To iterate over a `[hashtable]` you need to get an enumerator for it:

```
   $Hash.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        If (!(Test-Path $_.Name))
        {
            $map = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
            $map.MapNetworkDrive($_.Name, $_.Value, $true)
            Write-Host "Mapped That Stuff"
        }
        else
        {Write-Host ($_.Name) + ($_.Value)}
    }
```

Comment: Hello @briantist - thanks for your reply. Is it normal that if I run just this part from the script (with the hash of course). that there is a return which says:" Process[0]:" and wants me to put in some information? what is this

Comment: ok i got this one. the "{" has to be on the same line as `ForEach-Object`

Comment: @SimonS is correct. `ForEach-Object` is a cmdlet, unlike `foreach` which is a statement. Cmdlets are basically functions; they take parameters. With `ForEach-Object` you pass a `[ScriptBlock]` as a parameter, so it can't be on a new line unless you use backtick (but don't do that). This is one reason I prefer not to use C# style indentation/brace placement with PowerShell.

Answer (score 6):

I usually just use the `Keys` property of a hashtable to iterate over it. So your script would be:

```
$Hash = @{
    "h:" = "\\server\share";
    "i:" = "\\server\share";
    "j:" = "\\server\share";
    "k:" = "\\server\share";
    "p:" = "\\server\share";
    "z:" = "\\server\share";
    }
        $Hash.Keys | ForEach-Object
        {
            If (!(Test-Path $_))
            {
                $map = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
                $map.MapNetworkDrive($_, $Hasj.$_, $true)
                Write-Host "Mapped That Stuff"
            }
            else
            {Write-Host ($_) + ($Hash.$_)}
        }
```

Actually, after looking at it I think I'd take a shorter route, use a `Where` statement to just find the drives that don't exist, and then map those drives:

```
$Hash = @{
    "h:" = "\\server\share";
    "i:" = "\\server\share";
    "j:" = "\\server\share";
    "k:" = "\\server\share";
    "p:" = "\\server\share";
    "z:" = "\\server\share";
    }

$Hash.Keys | Where{!(Test-Path $_)} | ForEach{ New-PSDrive -Name $_.trim(':') -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Hash.$_ -Persist }
```

I used the `New-PSDrive` cmdlet there and the `-Persist` argument which then makes a standard Windows Mapped Drive that you can see and manage through Windows Explorer just like any other mapped drive. If you don't want that kind of mapping just remove the `-Persist` argument and it will then just be mapped for your script.